# shmget for IPC in linux

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

I'm really new to linux OS. Can someone say how to do this work with linux. I'm not asking the C code. It's hard to understand it. Thank you

1. First program creates a shared memory area using shmget() and maps it to its address space. Then it writes "Hello" in to that shared memory area. Then it waits until the first byte in the shared memory area becomes *.

2. The second program should be started after the first one. It maps the shared memory area created by the first program into its address space and reads the string and prints it to the terminal. Then it changes the first byte of the shared memory area to *.

Comment: And what have you tried? How did it work? How didn't it work? Can you be more specific with what part you're having trouble with? You *have* read the manual pages of the system calls involved? You *have* looked and searched for other examples (there are plenty)?

Comment: yes I've read many of those. First program and second program means do they have to be in separate c programs? or does it refer to two processes in the same C program?

Comment: Well, the assignment mentions first and second "program" and not "process".

Comment: well, what does it mean by "Then it waits until the first byte in the shared memory area becomes \* " ? what does the "\*" stands for?

Comment: In the first program, you simply wait (one way or other) until the second program changed the first byte from `'H'` to `'*'`. Did you even read the assignment, or just copy-pasted it here?

Comment: I read it for many times. I found it hard to understand. 
That means the " * " is just a character. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define SHSIZE 100

int main(){

    int shmid;
    char *shm;

    shmid = shmget(9876, SHSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    memcpy(shm, "Hello", 5);

    while(*shm != '*'){
    sleep(1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

And the client:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define SHSIZE 100

int main(){
    int shmid;
    char *shm,*s;

    shmid = shmget(9876, SHSIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    for(s = shm; *s != 0; s++){
    printf("%c", *s);
    }
    printf("\n");

    *shm = '*';

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you're asking how to use shared memory to exchange data between two programs. This is another form of IPC, or Inter-process communication.

Refer to this link for a video tutorial!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFRbX8u6lB0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This video isn't available anymore.