# What is the use of IPC_CREAT | 0666 flag in shmget() function in C

Tags: c, shared-memory

[shmget for IPC in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500476/shmget-for-ipc-in-linux)

Can someone explain what does the IPC_CREAT |0666 really do in shmget() unix system call in the above code, i know that 0666 is octal value here, but changing it does not have any effect at all.

Comment: It sets the permissions for the newly created shared memory segment to `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH` (read-write permissions for everyone) if it does not already exist.

Comment: so what could be the octal value set i can use after IPC_CREAT | .... , and if I set it to IPC_CREAT | 0600, does this mean only the program creating the shared memory segment have access to it? or does it mean it have access to anyone with the key?

Comment: If the segment was created with permissions 0600, only the user that created it has access to it. (Well, the superuser can access it too.) The permissions and ownership can be changed with `shmctl()`.

Comment: Did you consider reading [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html)?  Or [the other documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html)?  Or any of the documentation surrounding those?

Answer (score 12):

0666 is the usual access permision in linux in rwx octal format and having the sequence(owner-group-user). IPC_CREAT has the value of 512 in decimal as defined in the sys/ipc.h header file.

IPC_CREAT|0666 basically performs bitwise or of the two to set the flag in `shmget`, and both of them simply perform their usual functions.
0666 sets the access permissions of the memory segment while
IPC_CREAT tells the system to create a new memory segment for the shared memory.

If this flag is not used then `shmget()` will find the segment associated with key and check to see if the user has permission to access the segment.

Comment: IPC_CREAT is defined to be 0x01000 which corresponds to 4096. If it was 512, it would correspond to 0x200, meaning IPC_CREAT | 0666 = 0666, and IPC_CREAT would be redundant in this equation

Comment: @Adhamzhon Shukurov No, it's 01000 in octal, not 0x01000 in hex. 01000(oct) == 512 (dec). 0666 is octal too, so it's not redundant. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/ipc.h